# EF Core : nested entity foreign key not updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Assume the following table structure of a database.

[image]

There are three model classes mapping each of these tables as follows;

```
public class TableOne
{
    public TableOne () 
    {
        tabletwo = new TableTwo();
        tablethree = new TableThree();
    }

    public int col1:1 { get; set; }
    public int col2:2 { get; set; }
    public int col3:3 { get; set; }

    public virtual TableTwo tabletwo { get; set; }
    public virtual TableThree tablethree { get; set; }
}

public class TableTwo
{
    public TableTwo () 
    {
        tablethree = new TableThree();
    }

    public int col2:1 { get; set; }
    public int col2:2 { get; set; }
    // ref => TableOne col 1:1
    public int col1:1 { get; set; }
    
    public virtual TableThree tableThree { get; set; }
}

public class TableThree
{
    public TableThree () 
    {
        tableOne = new TableOne();
        tableTwo = new TableTwo();
    }

    public int col3:1 { get; set; }
    // ref => TableTwo col 2:1
    public int col2:1 { get; set; }
    // ref => TableOne col 1:1
    public int col1:1 { get; set; }
    public TableOne tableOne { get; set; }
    public TableTwo tableTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Assume the references are properly set in `DBContext.cs`.

The following code will populate model `TableOne` and add it the context.

```
TableOne one = new TableOne();
one.col1:1 = 1;
one.col1:2 = 2;
one.col1:3 = 3;
one.tabletwo.col2:1 = 4;
one.tabletwo.col2:2 = 5;
one.tabletwo.tableThree.col3:1 = 6;
DBContext.TableOne.Add(one);
```

But running this code, I get this error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (TableThree => col 1:1)

But this error does not happen when the relationship between `TableThree` and `TableOne` is removed.

Please consider the above code as a pseudo. The project is huge and I am trying to extract only the most relevant parts.

In short, the `grand child`, in this case `TableThree` does not get the `col1:1` updated from the `grand parent` in this case `TableOne`. But `col2:1` in `TableThree` is properly updated with the Key from the immediate parent, `TableTwo`

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Confused by your code. You decare `tabletwo` and `tablethree` as `TableTwo` and `TableThree` types, respectively but the initialize them as `HashSet<>`. Are these one-one or one-many relationships?

Comment: It also seems you're trying to insert a `TableOne` with foreign keys to other tables that you haven't inserted. That's a FK constraint.

Comment: I updated the code now to depict a one to one relationship. In the original code. these are many to many relationships, thus using a `HashSet`

Comment: Any solution to this please?